# How to update the variable secondPrice to the third else arguement?

Tags: java, integer

```
while (true){
                int secondPrice = 0;
                String bid = scanner.nextLine();;
                if (bid.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("The item " + auction.get(i).getName() + " was sold for " + secondPrice);
                    break;
                }
                if (Integer.valueOf(bid) <= auction.get(i).getPrice()){
                    System.out.println("Cannot bid lower than or equal to the amount given.");
                    System.out.println("Any bidders?");
                }
                else {
                    secondPrice += Integer.valueOf(bid) + 1;
                    auction.get(i).setPrice(Integer.valueOf(bid));
                    System.out.println("Price is now at " + Integer.valueOf(bid) + ". Any other bidders?");
                }
            }
```

When I run this, and I put some numbers on the scanner to raise the price, and when printing out secondPrice it's always 0, the same from the top.

Comment: I suspect the problem here is that `secondPrice` is declared inside the loop - so when it's printed out after `if (bid.isEmpty())` then yes, it will always be 0. But we don't know what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to help beyond suggesting "declare the variable before the start of the loop".

Comment: I want to write a program that does a second bidding system

Example is 
1st bid 3.00
2nd bid 4.00
3rd bid 5.00

3rd bidder highest bid, but he only pays 4.01

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the else-clause the OP does assign to secondPrice: ``secondPrice += Integer.valueOf(bid) + 1;``.

Comment: @NomadMaker you right, it's settled! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it is because secondPrice is being re-initialized every time, try declaring it before the while loop. A simple way to program the second bidding system you proposed, you would have a variable storing each bid, then set the highest bid equal to the second highest bid + .01 before the payment is calculated